# How to enable hint rectangle when holding

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I mean this, before right click (press and hold):

[image: taken from photo app]

Documentation [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding):

> Holding is intended for informational UI, but for interactions like displaying a context menu you should use RightTapped instead. You might handle Holding first **to display a hint that a menu will appear**, but to display the menu itself, use a RightTapped handler

And I want to use that transparent recangle, but documentation doesn't say how. Is there any simple way?

Comment: You just want it to display the mid opaque rectangle on holding? Does the rectangle display in the same spot regardless of where the holding is occuring on the parent element? Have you considered just a customized ToolTip style template on the parent element to accomplish the same thing and also provide the experience for MouseOver at the same time?

Comment: Ofcourse i considered that, but I hope there is more elegant solution (some build in functionality)

Comment: Well I mean it's an event right, so you could easily just hook up an EventTrigger to toggle visibility of your rectangle. Even if you wanted it in pure xaml it's a quickie.